# iOS Empty Space above the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift

When I check and calling the Viewcontroller from Appdelegate my app shows empty space above navigation bar I don't know what is the reason.

Here I give the code and screen shot.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let checkUserid = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "USERID")
    if checkUserid != nil {
        print(checkUserid!)
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)

        let revealViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RevealViewController") as? SWRevealViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: revealViewController!)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    else
    {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main" , bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
        navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

[image: Above the Home navigation bar it shows empty space.]

Comment: I think you were added the navigation bar in manually

Comment: i think @Anbu.Karthik is saying right. If you embedded that view controller in Navigation VC then you have that pass identifier of that Navigation VC in instantiateViewController method.

Comment: already he added the `UINavigationController` in window,

Comment: How to remove that navigation bar@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Thank You, Your points are helpful for me..@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to hide the default navigation bar.

Try adding the following code:

```
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```